# How to show my git branch in my command prompt on windows?

Tags: git

I've set up my windows machine to be unix like.

I've installed gitforwindows which includes git-bash

I am trying to show my current git branch in my command prompt but it isn't working.

I have `PS1=$TIME$USER$HOST$LOCATION$BRANCH` in by .bashrc

TIME, USER, HOST, LOCATION work ok, same as ubuntu and osx

However branch isn't showing and I get:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: command substitution: line 1: `git branch)'
```

BRANCH is:

```
BRANCH=' \[\033[00:33m\]$(git_branch) \[\033[00\]\n\$ '
```

and the git_branch function - which works ok when used in isolation is defined as:

`git_branch () {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'
  }`

Every format I've tried has failed :(

Rest of PS1 looks like this:

[image]

On UNIX when in a git repo I can see the branch like this:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for Super User?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve.... you can use all the git commands by just adding the `.../whatever-git-instal/bin/` to your path.Then just use normal git aliases (which are more portable) to produce command output...  It's not really a clear question - what tools are you using (other then git)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), one of Git's bash completion scripts, provides a function `__git_ps1` whose purpose is to show the current branch. It is much more robust than a simple call to `git branch`. Git bash should make this available out of the box.

You should be able to enable it by configuring your `PS1` to call `__git_ps1`, e.g.

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

This will include the user (`\u`), host (`\h`), and working directory (`\W`) as well as the branch, so you may be able to replace whatever `$USER`, `$HOST`, and `$LOCATION` are. I'm not sure what your `$TIME` does, but I trust you can figure out how to add that to the prompt yourself.