# git init not showing 'master', how do I change git-prompt.sh to show which branch I'm in?

Tags: git

As new git user, following udacity course 'version control with git', ran command `git init` text "Initialized empty Git repository in " followed by a path appeared but was expecting to see the word 'master' after user name.

`git .status`

shows

```
On branch master
...
```

Course said to move these files into home directory and rename first file and second folder to put . at start of name: bash_profile, git-completion.bash and git-prompt.sh, am checking they are in correct place.

[I need to study this question as it looks like it is related and it may answer the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49710598/how-to-show-my-git-branch-in-my-command-prompt-on-windows/49719172#49719172)

[The answer referred to this, I plan to study it for an answer and post findings here.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/468165c1d8a442994a825f3684528361727cd8c0/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh)

Comment: after the user name? Do you mean as part of the prompt? Some popular shell prompt configurations do that, but it's usually something you have to configure in your shell first. git status should show you what branch you're in.

Comment: @OhleC yes,... thanks for the comment...,looks like i'm in master branch, I'll review/note down my shell prompt config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy GIT-PROMPT.SH to temp dir.

Add following to .bashrc/.zshrc:
        source ~/.git-prompt.sh

Change PS1 to call __git_ps1 as a command-substitution:

`PS1='[\u@\h \W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '`

Answer (score 3):

In the udacity course it asked to paste the code they given in the ***.bash_profile*** file in the user's home directory. Insted paste the code they gave in the ***.bashrc*** file in the user's home directory. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this highlighted part. This will not show by default in most command lines. I am using PowerShell core with Posh-git (https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git).

[image]

Comment: yes! that's it, I think  need to identify shell prompt configurations, I've made

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `.zshrc`

```
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit
autoload -Uz vcs_info
precmd_vcs_info() { vcs_info }
precmd_functions+=( precmd_vcs_info )
setopt prompt_subst
RPROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}'
# PROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}%# '
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%b'
```

Source: [Git in Zsh](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Zsh)